# Generic object in graphQL mutation argument

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm building a GraphQL app, and all is mostly making sense so far. I've now gotten to the point where I want a modal component to delete an element.

In previous Redux apps I've made an action creator that takes in the operation, object type and the object, e.g:
`this.props.openModal('delete','task',taskObject)`

...however with GraphQL you need to specify exactly what schema type any mutation is expecting. Is this approach still possible? Or do I need to make a different modal mutation definition for every single object type in the app?

I guess converting it to a JSON string might do, but feels messy. So far GraphQL just seems like tons and tons of repetition, and I'm trying to keep that to a minimum, y'know?

Answer (score 0):

Whelp, never mind. Apollo doesn't type-check @client mutations, so it's a non-issue for now.